# How to find all cycles in undirected graph with python-graph?

Tags: python, graph, pygraph

I'm using python-graph and would like to find all cycles in an undirected graph. I'm trying find_cycle() but that returns only one cycle, even if the graph has more than one.

Is there any other function for this in python-graph? In another graph package?